# How can $\underset{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^2}{\text{min}} \frac{1}{2}\langle x, Ax \rangle + \langle B,x \rangle + c$ be unbounded

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, hessian-matrix

I have a few questions regarding the optimisation problem.

1. I was told that when A is semi positive definite (implying the function is convex) and A is symmetric, $\underset{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^2}{\text{min}} \frac{1}{2}\langle x, Ax \rangle + \langle B,x \rangle + c$ optimal value may be unbounded. How can this be so when it is a quadratic? And apparently if it is bounded, there could be many optimal solutions? How and could any examples be provided? Can this be extended to $\mathbb{R}^n$?
2. When A is positive definite, I believe the function is strongly convex but I can't figure out what scalar of the identity the hessian (which is A) would be greater than.
3. When A is indefinite, the function becomes non convex. Would this mean it is always unbounded below?

Comment: $x_1^2+x_2$ is unbounded while $x_1^2$ has many optimal solutions.

Comment: In one dimension we minimize $\frac{a}{2}x^2+bx+c$, and semi-defnite means $a \ge 0$.  If it is not definite, that means $a=0$.  So in one dimension, could the function $bx+c$ be unbounded below?  It is similar in two dimensions.